# Regarding creating a new variable in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have a SQL table (temp2) like this:

[image]

I want to calculate the balance*rate/sum(balance) for each cat

So, my desired output would be something like this:

[image]

To get this output, I used following code:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp3;
create table temp3 as select cat, balance * rate /sum(balance) as prod from temp2
group by cat 

select temp2.emp_id, temp2.cat,temp2.balance, temp2.rate , temp3.prod from temp2 
left outer join temp3 on temp2.cat=temp3.cat
```

So here I have created a new table to get the answer.
Will there be an easier way to get the same results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for the new table unless you need to refer to it in multiple queries. You can just join with a subquery.

```
SELECT t2.emp_id, t2.cat, t2.balance, t2.rate, t3.prod
FROM temp2 AS t2
JOIN (
    SELECT cat, balance * rate /sum(balance) AS prod 
    FROM temp2
    GROUP BY cat
) AS t3 ON t2.cat = t3.cat
```

There's no need to use `LEFT JOIN`. Since the subquery gets `cat` from the same table, there can't be any non-matching rows.

Sometimes it's useful to create the new table so you can add an index for performance reasons.

Comment: You and OP both have the same issue of using a non-aggregate value in a grouped select - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need a join or subquery at all thanks to window functions:

```sql
SELECT emp_id, cat, balance, rate,
       balance * rate / sum(balance) OVER (PARTITION BY cat) AS prod
FROM temp2
ORDER BY emp_id;
```

gives

```
emp_id  cat  balance  rate  prod              
------  ---  -------  ----  ------------------
1       1    1000.0   0.25  0.0625            
2       3    1250.0   0.25  0.0568181818181818
3       2    1500.0   0.25  0.0681818181818182
4       1    1000.0   0.25  0.0625            
5       2    1250.0   0.25  0.0568181818181818
6       3    1500.0   0.25  0.0681818181818182
100     1    1000.0   0.25  0.0625            
101     3    1250.0   0.25  0.0568181818181818
102     2    1500.0   0.25  0.0681818181818182
103     1    1000.0   0.25  0.0625            
104     2    1250.0   0.25  0.0568181818181818
105     3    1500.0   0.25  0.0681818181818182
```

(Create an index on `temp2.cat` for best performance).

This is also more accurate; both yours and Barmar's uses `balance` and `rate` in the grouped query without including those values in the `GROUP BY` clause - that's an error in most databases, but Sqlite will pick a random row from the group to use as the values, which when different rows in the group have different values for them, will throw off the final calculations. To do it properly with grouping (If, for example, you're using an old database version that doesn't support window functions), you need something like

```sql
SELECT t2.emp_id, t2.cat, t2.balance, t2.balance * t2.rate / t3.sumbalance AS prod
FROM temp2 AS t2
JOIN (SELECT cat, sum(balance) AS sumbalance
      FROM temp2
      GROUP BY cat) AS t3
ON t2.cat = t3.cat
ORDER BY t2.emp_id;
```